# array = null; C# unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

До недавного времени, если мне надо было обнулить массив - пользовался способом вида

```
private Vector3[] coord;
coord = new Vector3[15];
coord = null;
```

И всё работало. 
Но недавно наткнулся на

```
Array.Clear - метод (Array, Int32, Int32)
```

Т.е. получается, что всё это время у меня не обнулялись массивы? Или это просто некий синтаксический сахар?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это совершенно два разных действия. 
Разберем каждый случай:

Здесь создаем ссылку на будущий массив:

```
private Vector3[] coord;
```

Здесь инициализируем эту ссылку собственно массивом на 15 элементов,
где каждый из 15 элементов равен `null`:

```
coord = new Vector3[15];
```

Здесь делаем ссылку пустой (Возвращаем в состояние, как после первой строки),
при этом массив на 15 элементов, созданный во второй строке будет потерян, его удалит сборщик мусора в будущем (если больше не делали ссылок на него):

```
coord = null;
```

Теперь второй случай с `Array.Clear`:

Этот метод проходит по существующему массиву и обнуляет каждый его элемент, т.е. осуществляет операцию `coord[i] = null` для каждого `i`

То есть разница в том, что либо мы обнуляем всю ссылку, либо обнуляем элементы.

Давайте на простом примере массива строк:

```
String[] strings; //имеем ссылку `strings - null`
strings = new String[3];
strings[0] = "Вася";
strings[1] = "Петя";
strings[2] = "Миша";
strings = null; //По факту наш массив с Васей, Петей и Мишей ещё жив, до запуска сборщика мусора, но обратиться к нему мы уже не можем, так как ссылка на объект потеряна
```

Если сделать вот так:

```
String[] strings; //имеем ссылку `strings - null`
strings = new String[3];
strings[0] = "Вася";
strings[1] = "Петя";
strings[2] = "Миша";
String[] vasyaPetyaMisha = strings; //Создали ещё одну ссылку на массив
strings = null;//Вася Петя Миша все ещё живы по ссылке vasyaPetyaMisha
```

С `Arrays.Clear`:

```
String[] strings; //имеем ссылку `strings - null`
strings = new String[3];
strings[0] = "Вася";
strings[1] = "Петя";
strings[2] = "Миша";
Array.Clear(strings, 0, 3); //strings[0] = null,
                            //strings[1] = null,
                            //strings[2] = null;
                            //Васи Пети Миши больше нет
```

Что лучше? Зависит от задачи. В первом случае вы не очищаете массив, а забываете о нём (или пересоздаёте его, если конечно в будущем снова будете инициализировать `coords`). То есть у вас выделится память под этот массив в каком-то другом месте. Во втором случае выделенная область памяти будет переиспользована.